# DRF (ListAPIView) - how to apply search filter in queryset

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I want to fetch the result if the user enters something

Example - if in search box the user enters 'Hello World', then it should only fetch 'Hello World' through DRF ListView.

Views.Py

```
class FunderViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
  
    serializer_class = FunderSerializer
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Funder.objects.all()
        name = self.request.query_params.get('term')
        if name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(Funder_name=name)
        return queryset
```

URLS.py

```
path(
    'funder/<term>',
    funder.FunderViewSet.as_view(),
    name='funder-lookup'
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookups for search.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Funder.objects.all()
    name = self.request.query_params.get('term')
    if name is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(Funder_name__exact=name)
    return queryset
```

for more example you can read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/lookups/).